# Django throws error message "'loaders' option is empty"

Tags: django

I'm trying to move to the new Django 1.8 settings with regard to templates, and am getting following error message:

> Django couldn't find any templates because your 'loaders' option is empty!

Here is my TEMPLATES setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

"Loaders" also needs to be specified in `TEMPLATES` if not specified as `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`:

```
        'loaders': [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ],
```

The alternative is to specify `'APP_DIRS': True,`.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/